# save printed results from a loop to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops

How can I save loops from a print in a for loop to a dataframe?

Code I want to save

```
for div in soup.select('[id^=post_message]'):
  print(div.get_text("\n", strip=True))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dataframe and append into it for each iteration. Or better still create a list, append into list for each step and then create a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = list()
for div in soup.select('[id^=post_message]'):
    df.append(div.get_text("\n", strip=True))
df = pd.Dataframe(df)
```

Comment: probably you meant `df.append` instead of `print`